# Fill color for an arc drawed by canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to fill color for an arc. But, I don't want to use `ctx.lineWidth` to do that.

I try to draw it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj4Jm/42/). Please teach me how to fill color for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a continuous path to be able to *fill* it with a single color if you don't want to use line-width.

Using two arcs means you need to "reverse" one of them so their end-points connect correctly without crossing. You can do this by using the *counter-close wise* flag at the end set to true and swap start and end angles:

```
ctx.arc(W/2, H, H-40, 2*Math.PI, Math.PI, true);  // CCW, swapped angles
ctx.arc(W/2, H, H, Math.PI, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();                                       // now it can be filled
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/Pj4Jm/45/)**

Comment: @user4557573 it's because the bottom arc should have been on top and vica versa. It's better to reduce the radius of the bottom one: http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/Pj4Jm/46/

Comment: yes, you're right. I forgot put the code drawing the bottom arc before the code drawing the top arc. But, why do that? Could you explain more? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user4557573 otherwise the end points will cross. The path is rendered butt to butt: startpath1-endpath1 startpath2-endpath2 etc. If they are not in order the path lines will cross and the result be thereafter. It's important to keep track of start end points so they are continuous.

Comment: K3N, yeah! I got your explanation. It like I draw square ABCD (A->B->C->D->A). It is wrong if I draw A->B->D->C, the lines will cross. Thank again.